# Chrome extension, getting devtools HAR data

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, har

Is it possible to get the [HAR (HTTP Archive)](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/) for a page from the google chrome extension? I want to get how long it takes to load a website with my plugin.

Comment: Please refer to [this doc](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devtools.network.html#method-getHAR)

Comment: Also I found this blog post: http://blog.chromium.org/2011/10/new-developer-tools-experimental-apis.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use chrome.devtools.network to get the HAR file as per
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.network.html

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking to get the HAR data of your extension, or are you asking about geting the load time of a browser using your plugin?  Either way, Google Developer Tools -> Network -> right click, save HAR file.